# Is my SSD performing poorly?

Tags: performance, windows-8, ssd

Recently I've noticed that my SSD, which is a Crucial model CT128V4SSD2, is performing really really poorly. I took a benchmark test and here's the result:

[image]

In addition, I noticed from the Task Manager dialog in Windows 8 that the response time of the drive is very long.

[image]

Is my SSD having serious problems? Is there a way to identify what's causing the slowness?

Comment: the benchmark images don't load for me, could you use the "upload" picture button to host them properly?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know there's an upload picture button. Thanks for editing the question.

Comment: No I didn't notice any slowness before. The only thing I change recently is installing a new graphics card.

Comment: How full is the drive? Is TRIM enabled? See [here](http://forums.legitreviews.com/about23670.html) for info on how to check that.

Comment: The drive still has 81 GB free out of 120GB. TRIM is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the picture. Is tells you that you run the SSD in IDE mode (PCIIDE) instead of AHCI (MSHACI/AMD_sata). So go into the BIOS and change the mode to AHCI.

Attention, enable the AHCI drivers first or you'll get the 0x7B STOP code "INACCESSABLE_BOOT_DEVICE".

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976

The key is renamed in Windows 8 to StorAHCI instead of Msahci, the rest is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does it mean for SSD, I have to use AHCI mode? I didn't know this.

Comment: always run all HDDs in AHCI mode. This improves performance a lot.

Comment: I've just checked my BIOS, and it has only the RAID mode. There's no AHCI mode. will RAID mode help?

Comment: which motherboard do you use?

Comment: It's the default motherboard that comes with Dell Studio 540: IPIEL-RN2 Motherboard

Comment: According to this site: http://forums.crucial.com/t5/Solid-State-Drives-SSD/ICH10-chipset-but-no-AHCI-in-BIOS-Any-work-arounds-to-run-C300/m-p/70267#M21678

using RAID does the same like AHCI. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

According to the specs for your drive:

> [Newegg Product Description](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148585)
>   Performance
>   Max Sequential Read
>   Up to 230 MB/s
>   Max Sequential Write
>   Up to 175 MB/s
>   4KB Random Read
>   Up to 10,000 IOPS
>   4KB Random Write
>   Up to 4,000 IOPS
>   MTBF
>   1,200,000 hours

That suggests that your read is about there, the write is a bit slow (but you aren't doing sequential in some of those tests - so not alarming).

The seek time is pretty questionable though.  Might be a sign that it was formatted poorly, oddly enough.  SSD's are a bit more particular about that (the best tool I have read of/used is [Parted](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=downloads)).

Comment: Sequential writes are pretty slow, 76 MB/s vs. 175 MB/s in the specs. 4K reads and writes are also rather slow. Specs give 39 MB/s for reads and 15.6 MB/s for writes, but OP's drive gets 16 MB/s and 3.8 MB/s respectively.

Comment: Are you suggesting I'm using Parted to reformat my drive?

Comment: @Indrek, what is OP's drive?

Comment: Original Poster's (SSD)drive.

Comment: @superkinhluan "OP" means "original poster", so in this case, you. I'm referring to the benchmark results you posted in your question.

Comment: @page4096 How do I check if my partition is not properly aligned? The drive has only one partition.

Comment: Ah, my bad, read the wrong results from the screenshots. 4K reads are still a bit slow - specs give 39 MB/s but OP's drive gets only 10.7 MB/s. Interestingly, 4K *writes* are faster than specced - 22.6 vs. ~15.6 MB/s.

Comment: The green "1024 K - OK" text tells you that it's aligned, I edited my previous comment.

Comment: What is happening right now is that every operation, e.g. opening web page, opening app, playing music, etc. is very slow.

Comment: I am curious if it is a Windows8 issue - because the benchie looks pretty reasonable for that specific drive (which isn't rated terribly well).  However, the Win8 Task manager makes me wonder if the OS is handing it poorly.  Did you just upgrade?  Also, did you do any tweaks to make W8 handle the drive better?